# How to do nested aggregation in python polars? Translate from Pandic please

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

Im transitioning from pandas, so please excuse my non-parallelized brain. Suppose we have following pandas code:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({val:np.random.randint(1,5,100) for val in ['a','b','c','d','x','y','z']})
(
dfx
.groupby('a')
.apply(
    lambda df:
    df
    .sort_values('c')
    .groupby('d')
    [['x','y','z']]
    .agg(['max','mean','median'])
    )
)
```

Output (with smooshed multiindex to paste it here):

| a | d | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | x | x | x | y | y | y | z | z | z |
|  |  | sum | mean | median | sum | mean | median | sum | mean | median |
| 1 | 1 | 15.0 | 3.75 | 4.0 | 12.0 | 3.0 | 3.5 | 12.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 9.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 5.0 | 1.666667 | 1.0 | 9.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |
| 1 | 3 | 33.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 30.0 | 2.727273 | 3.0 | 27.0 | 2.454545 | 2.0 |
| 1 | 4 | 23.0 | 2.8750 | 3.0 | 16.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 15.0 | 1.8750 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 18.0 | 2.571429 | 2.0 | 13.0 | 1.857143 | 2.0 | 18.0 | 2.571429 | 3.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 18.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 23.0 | 2.555556 | 2.0 | 25.0 | 2.777778 | 3.0 |
| 2 | 3 | 11.0 | 3.666667 | 4.0 | 9.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 9.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |
| 2 | 4 | 3.0 | 1.50 | 1.50 | 6.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| 3 | 1 | 28.0 | 2.80 | 3.0 | 21.0 | 2.10 | 2.0 | 29.0 | 2.90 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 2 | 13.0 | 2.166667 | 2.0 | 19.0 | 3.166667 | 3.0 | 18.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 3 | 16.0 | 1.777778 | 2.0 | 22.0 | 2.444444 | 3.0 | 32.0 | 3.555556 | 4.0 |
| 3 | 4 | 20.0 | 2.222222 | 2.0 | 23.0 | 2.555556 | 2.0 | 23.0 | 2.555556 | 3.0 |
| 4 | 1 | 9.0 | 2.250 | 2.0 | 10.0 | 2.50 | 2.50 | 5.0 | 1.250 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 2 | 19.0 | 3.166667 | 3.0 | 8.0 | 1.333333 | 1.0 | 22.0 | 3.666667 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 3 | 10.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 14.0 | 2.80 | 3.0 | 15.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 |
| 4 | 4 | 9.0 | 2.250 | 2.0 | 12.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 10.0 | 2.50 | 2.50 |

How to rewrite it in polars?

The core idea of the exercise is that in `apply` i can do something with the whole dataframe group, e.g. sort it and then aggregate (which doesnt make sense, i know, but the idea is freedom to do **whatever**). Do i lose this freedom if i want my code to be parallelizable or is there a  way to catch the whole group? I tried `pl.all()` but couldnt figure out the trick to at least sort each sub-df

Comment: The Polars Cookbook has a page dedicated to this topic.  There are lots of great examples on how to use Polars' powerful Expression syntax to avoid using apply and/or nested groupby contexts.  https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/groupby.html

Comment: @cbilot i have read the page, but it didnt make me a `polars` programmer. I still want the freedom of 10-fold-nested .groupby().appply()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with the latter part of your question, I think the Polars way to approach having sub-dataframes would be to use `over` to window:

```py
dfplx = pl.DataFrame(dfx)
dfplx.select([
        'a', 'b',
        pl.col(["x", "y", "z"]).sort_by('c').over(['a', 'd']),
        pl.col("x").sort_by('c').mean().over(['a', 'd'].alias("x mean")
])
```

If you want to use apply with windows, that's entirely possible (`.list()` makes polars expect multiple results from the lambda):

```py
dfplx.select([
        'a', 'b', 'c', 
        pl.col(['x', 'y', 'z'])
           .sort_by('c')
           .apply(lambda x: [x.mean(), x.median(), x.max()])
           .list()
           .over(['a', 'd'])
    ])
```

For a complete translation the most concise method I found was to simply generate the list of columns you want:

```py
dfplx.select(['a', 'b'] + 
            [pl.col(a)
                .sort_by('c') # sort for some reason ;)
                .apply(func) # apply the [max, mean, median] function
                .over(['a', 'd']) # window by a then d
                .alias(f"{a} {label}")  # rename the result
            for a in ['x', 'y', 'z']
            for label, func in [("max", pl.max), ("mean", pl.mean), ("median", pl.median)]
        ])
```

Comment: i didnt downwote it, but running your complete translation generates a 100 rows - which is not what pandas outputs, could you explain what did you want to do?

Comment: aha! For some reason, function over column returns the same length as input, i fixed it with
.distinct()
.sort(['a','d'])
but isnt it costly to broadcast values and then drop duplicates?